# ACC API - Project User Endpoint - Products without Matching Enum for cloudWorksharing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am working through a project where I am extending the API for an add-in in Revit and when I try to pass the "cloudWorksharing" Product Key as described in the API reference I get a 400 error saying "No enum match".

[API Reference](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projects-project-Id-users-POST/)
[API enum List from reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHMvL.png)

[Status Message from Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noPcI.png)

I have successfully used other enums like projectAdministration or docs, so I am confident my call is correct. Is this an enum that doesn't actually do anything since really cloudWorksharing is a product of the user's license?

I was expecting the product type to be applied to the user.

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait. As I remember, worksharing is sperate license than ACC modules. It looks you are using ACC Admin API v1 to import users to project with the enum option. https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projects-project-Id-users-POST/ .  If checking v2 API https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-v2-projects-project-Id-users-import-POST/, I do not seem to find this option. I am checking with engineer team to clarify it. May I know your purpose is to enable worksharing for specific user when he works in Revit?

Comment: Thanks @XiaodongLiang, as I was starting with the Docs I assumed if I wanted them to have access I needed to include worksharing as a product since it was on the list. Now that time has gone by I see how / why it is more a licensing thing than a product. Seems like it should be removed from the documentation and/or annotated to indicate it isn't available.
Thanks for the tip on the import users, the main guide still lists it as V1, but I see now in the url it is V2. I will look more into that.